# Ionicons: How to add custom icons?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionicons

How can i add custom icons to ionicons?
I could not yet find a step by step instruction what to do.
There are many really basic icons (like the paragraph icon 
for example) which are not provided by ionicons, so i somehow
have to add them by my own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Download the fonts to include in our project.  Go ahead and download the latest Font Awesome release and extract them.  Copy the following font files into your www/fonts directory:

1. ontawesome-webfont.ttf
2. fontawesome-webfont.eot
3. fontawesome-webfont.svg
4. fontawesome-webfont-woff
5. fontawesome-webfont.otf
   Next we need to edit www/css/style.css to include this new font set for use in our project.  Add the following lines:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'fontawesome';
    src:url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot');
    src:url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Every time we want to use the Font Awesome set we just set our font family as fontawesome.

Get More custom icons https://icomoon.io/

Comment: Your answer talk about the fonts. How do we add custom icons? The icons that we create on our own, not a third party library.

Comment: fontawesome have the lot of icons.